# Remove extra blank row from navbarPage Shiny layout

Tags: r, shiny

I'm developing a Shiny app using both navbarPage and sidebarPanel layouts. However, an extra empty row keeps being appended right below the navigation bar (see image below). In the HTML file, I can clearly see the culprit:

```
<div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
```

However, I can't seem to figure out which part of my R code is causing that extra row to be created. For the reference, below is a minimum `ui.R` code that illustrates the issue:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  navbarPage('Minimum Example',
    tabPanel('Tab1',
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(br()),
        mainPanel(br())
      )
    )
)))
```

[image: Extra blank row below navigation tab and above sidebarpanel]

Comment: I don't think you can.  I imagine it is the default to not have the body pressed tight against the navigation bar.  If you want to change that you may need to try petitioning to the package maintainers on [github](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues).

Comment: I don't seem to see this issue on their navbar example [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/navbar-example.html) though.It seems that somehow this only happens when you combine a navbar with a sidebarLayout.

Comment: Have you tried running the example on your machine?  There still is that space there when I run both yours and the example.

Comment: Yep. You're right :) Running it locally creates that same issue. That's really odd that the example on their webpage doesn't have the extra row. Thanks for the note! I guess I'll leave the question open in case anyone comes up with an alternative.

Comment: If it really bugs you, I seriously would suggest bringing it up directly with the maintainers (see github link above).  If it is a bug, they will be the ones most likely to fix it.

Comment: Just did that! Thanks for the directions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was actually happening due to an extra `&nbsp;` being added to the header by default as seen [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/b9c6b84ff5f120311466aec93540221b88ba3f91/R/bootstrap.R#L253-L255). Using `navbarPage(header = "")` is an workaround that avoids that.

Full credit for the solution goes to [wch](https://github.com/wch) and [jjallaire](https://github.com/jjallaire) in the Shiny development team. More details can be found [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/722#issuecomment-72981536).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to remove it but adding the styling information below to your css file will make the gap between the navbar and the other parts of the page smaller overall.

```
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't quite solve the problem because there is an actual blank row there and suppressing the overall spacing causes some other areas of the layout to look a bit unpleasant.